# Websphere in windows unable to make call over SSL

Tags: java, ssl, ejb, websphere

I have a web application (pure UI) deployed in my local machine in websphere. This application gets connected to a different application (Backend) deployed in a linux box (RHEL 7.1).

I had enabled the SSL for both inbound and outbound communications in the transport layer of websphere config where my backend application is deployed. My intention is to enable the SSL communication between the UI and backend application.

For this on the client side which is my UI application i had changed the `ssl.client.props and sas.client.props` to point it to the correct keystore and trust store location and passing it as vm arguments like this in `server.xml` file.

```
-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:/C:/locationOf/ssl.client.props 
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/C:/locationOf/sas.client.props
```

But somehow it looks like that websphere (Ui app) is not reading these properties file and trying to make a connection using simple TCP rather that SSL. Below is the exception which I am getting everytime

```
 java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:381)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:370)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:359)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:93)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1983)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2008)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1186)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1272)
```

I did some research about this exception and it comes in the case when on the server you have SSL-Required enabled and in the client side you are not providing or websphere is not picking up the `sas.client.props` file.

I had also written a simple standalone client and with this client I am successfully able to do the EJB lookup on the backend application and also able to reproduce the same exception when I am not providing the vm argument for sas.client.props file.

So my question here is what is correct way and where to provide the properties file as vm arguments so that websphere can pick up these. ??

**Note :** When i deployed the same UI application in a linux box ,I am able to make the successful call over SSL. Here , I didn't provide the location of any of these files as vm arguments explicitly. They were picked up automatically from the file `setupCmdLine.sh` .

I think that there is something different in which websphere is configured in windows and linux. ( I may be wrong)

**Websphere version : 8.5.5**

Any help or pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Is your UI app a stand alone or web app (war) deployed in WebSphere? If it is web app, then dont change any *.props file, but configure your SSL via web admin console. You have to add certificate to the trust store. How you are making connection from your UI code?

Comment: In the UI app we are doing a look up for the ejb bean deployed on the other server. Its an ear.